# Get cell value from powershell result set

Tags: powershell

The command

`Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical | select Name -first 1`

has the output which you can see in the screenshot:

[image: https://gyazo.com/375bd8449c95a130b2218b63e04d9d30]

How can I get the `value` from the column `Name` which in this case is *Ethernet*?

I want to use the output in another script to specify a DNS like:

`netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver \"Ethernet\" address=127.0.0.1 index=1`

As you can see I have to provide the network interface name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` Parameter of `Select-Object`

If you expand the Name Property, it will only return the value:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical | select -ExpandProperty Name -first 1
Ethernet 2
```

You could also do this, but i'd rather use `ExpandProperty`:

```
(Get-NetAdapter -Name * -Physical).Name | select -first 1
```